# No suggestion Edit Text with multiline in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to implement **Multiline EditText with no suggession** in android. I have googled a lot and I found below code :

```
noticeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

or

```
noticeEditText.setInputType( android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD );
```

or

In layout file :

```
 android:inputType="textFilter"
```

But my **problem** is that, with no suggestion, Edit Text is of **single line**.
I have add below properties also :

```
noticeEditText.setSingleLine(false);
noticeEditText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
noticeEditText.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

But still getting **single line** Edit Text View. What should I do for getting **Multiline edit text view with no suggestion**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try this and you will be happy:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

It should work for you well.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am checking above suggestion and will reply soon, thanks again.

Comment: I have applied your given suggestion, but still having same problem, Edit Text is of single line. With no suggestion, Edit Text is of single line, not able to get multiline edit text view. Please provide some other solution. Thanks.

Comment: Create new project and add EditText. Apply my solution. Is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

In your Layout File `.xml`, for your `EditText` you can set different attributes that suit your needs. For your current requirement, add this to the Edit Text.

```
<EditText
   ....
   android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am checking above suggestion and will reply soon, thanks again.

Comment: I have applied your given suggestion, but still having same problem, Edit Text is of single line. With no suggestion, Edit Text is of single line, not able to get multiline edit text view. Please provide some other solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem in my code too and to solve this, I used @Marek solution in my .xml file -
`android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"`

and removed following from java file -
`.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);`